# best way to split this table into smaller ones

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have this table for statistics but it's taking me forever to run the queries I need. What would be a good way to split it into smaller tables? most of the queries are run on username, value and functions.
Here's the table:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DATE                                               DATE
 MACHINE                                            VARCHAR2(25)
 FUNCTION                                           VARCHAR2(100)
 VALUE                                              NUMBER(7,3)
 APPLICATION                                        VARCHAR2(40)
 USERNAME                                           VARCHAR2(25)
 WORKSTATION                                        VARCHAR2(25)
 IPADDR                                             VARCHAR2(25)
 GLOB_NAME                                          VARCHAR2(60)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to split it? What does the data in it mean? What are the indexes? What sort of query are you running?

Comment: It is impossible to answer this if you don't provide your queries. Splitting is not likely to be necessary, indexing is another matter

Comment: You should never split a table for performance reasons that should be one table. When proper indexes and good written queries still perform bad then vertical partitioning is what you want. It's the job of the database then to split the data. Your view is still one table and it is not polluted.

Answer (score -1):

You should split the table only to avoid duplication.  So, if you have a ton of duplicate entries for "Machine", for example, create a Machine table with PK/FK.  Similarly for Application, etc.  It's odd to have so many VARCHAR's in one table, there is probably a lot of duplication there that could be FK's that refer to another table.

Comment: the table tracks users, what functions they use (cerner application) and the time the function takes. i have another table where i load the session for a specific user and then compare his functions time to the normal average from the main table.

Comment: i was given the table to work with it to get reports and i know it could be a lot better. yes there are a lot of duplicates: functions username...

Comment: wherever there are duplicates, split that into a PK/FK relationship to remove the duplicates.  Your joins then will prevent scans of varchar's, which will be faster